# Graphical interface in Embedded System

Tags: user-interface, embedded

I am building an automation system and i need to have graphical interface. Can i have graphical interface without a raspberry and an operating system in general?

with a simple microprocessor for example? (i think the answer is no)

what are my other options? An fpga board for example?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: There exist graphics-capable displays that can be connected to a microcontroller. But in this case, you may need to draw the interface manually (draw buttons, labels, ...), or you may find a display with some utility library to facilitate your life. See http://ugfx.io/ for example.

Comment: There are many GUI libraries for embedded systems. The appropriate choice will be dependent on your target and display technology which you have not specified. Moreover questions asking for recommendations for libraries are generally off topic on SO.  Google is a good resource for product search!

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! i will try to use such libraries for my project.

Answer (score 1):

There are many UI libraries designed for embedded targets such as Segger's emWin, uGFX, Microchip's graphics library etc. No fruit required for any of them, but a suitable microcontroller and LCD/TFT will be.

Comment: Thank you Colin! I will make a good research on the libraries and see what is better for my project.